# Как получить данные из базы данных?

Tags: c#, mysql

У меня есть бд, которая выглядит таким образом:

[image: database]

Как получить group_name?

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT group_name FROM groups WHERE 
username = @username;", Connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", "nickname");
MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
  while (reader.Read())
  {
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(reader["group_name"]));
  }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a20kw6s4(v=vs.110).aspx

или

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(reader[0]));
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsa8xa84(v=vs.110).aspx